# GitHub readme.md

Tags: github, syntax, documentation

I want to create a readme.md file for my GitHub but not really sure how to populate it with the correct syntax in order for it to display correctly. Would anyone know if there is a site with tutorials on how to populate the readme.md with the correct synatx? Or additionally, is it acceptable to replace the readme.md file with another format like html.

Comment: it is called markdown https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are not familiar with `Markdown` syntax, GitHub official has provided an awesome tutorial called [github-flavored-markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) for you to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I use this http://dillinger.io/ it is more helpful.